# How to handle entity relationships when using a stored procedure to update database?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using a stored procedure to update  a holiday booking to a database. The stored procedure is inserting to multiple tables with relationships. How do I handle these relationships in the stored procedure.

Thank you

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE SPBookingUpdate
(
@BookingDate date,
@TripStartDate date,
@NumberOfPeople tinyint,
@CardHolderName char(50),
@CardNumber char(16),
@ExpiryMonth char(3),
@ExpiryYear char (4),
@SecurityCode char(3),
@First_Name char (15), 
@Last_Name char (20), 
@Email_Address char (70),
@Phone_Number char(15),
@TotalDue money,
@PaymentDate date
)
AS BEGIN

INSERT INTO Booking (BookingDate, TripStartDate, NumberOfPeople)
VALUES(@BookingDate, @TripStartDate, @NumberOfPeople)

INSERT INTO CreditCard (CardHolderName, CardNumber, ExpiryMonth, ExpiryYear, SecurityCode) 
VALUES(@CardHolderName, @CardNumber, @ExpiryMonth, @ExpiryYear, @SecurityCode)

INSERT INTO Customers (First_Name, Last_Name, Email_Address, Phone_Number)
VALUES(@First_Name, @Last_Name, @Email_Address, @Phone_Number)

INSERT INTO Payments (TotalDue, PaymentDate)
VALUES(@TotalDue, @PaymentDate)
END


CREATE TABLE Customers
(CustomerID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
First_Name char(15) NOT NULL, 
Last_Name char (20) NOT NULL,
Email_Address char(70) NOT NULL,
Phone_Number char(15) NOT NULL);
GO


CREATE TABLE CreditCard
(CreditCardID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
CardHolderName char(50) NOT NULL,
CardNumber char(16) NOT NULL,
ExpiryMonth char(3) NOT NULL,
ExpiryYear char(4) NOT NULL,
SecurityCode char(3) NOT NULL);
GO

CREATE TABLE Holidays
(HolidayID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
HolidayName char(50) NOT NULL,
PlaceAvailability int NOT NULL,
NumberOfDaysOnPackage tinyint NOT NULL,
PricePerPerson money NOT NULL,
BriefDescription char(450) NOT NULL )
GO

CREATE TABLE Booking
(BookingID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
HolidayID int NOT NULL REFERENCES Holidays(HolidayID),
CustomerID int NOT NULL REFERENCES Customers(CustomerID),
BookingDate date NOT NULL,
TripStartDate date NOT NULL,
NumberOfPeople tinyint NOT NULL
)
GO



CREATE TABLE Payments
(PaymentID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
BookingID int NOT NULL REFERENCES Booking(BookingID),
CreditCardID int NOT NULL REFERENCES CreditCard(CreditCardID),
TotalDue money NOT NULL,
PaymentDate date NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: How do you know which credit card belongs to which customer? Seems like there is a hole in the design there. Unless you plan on joining the customers table to the booking table then the payments then back to credit cards, but that seems pretty inefficient. What happens if there is no payment or a payment is deleted? Now you can't determine which credit card belongs to which customer. I think at minimum you need a FK from credit cards to customer, even before you start writing a proc to fill those tables.

Comment: SO, should I add CustomerID as a foreign key on the on the CreditCard table ??

Comment: Well I certainly think that is best for data integrity. In the front end of your application how do you enter a credit card and associate it with a customer? Or are the credit cards only associated with payments?

Comment: Following from this how can I address my initial question?

Comment: It doesn't address your initial question, sorry. Just pointing out you may have a big problem in the design. What you need to do is write insert statements with OUTPUT values, set those OUTPUT values to variables so you can use them to insert into your other tables. Like when you insert into customers you need to set the output customerid as something, then in your next inserts where customerid is required (i.e. payments) you can pass your variable value.

Comment: Hi Jacob, with reference to your frist comment. I was thinking that each booking has a credit card but the customer may not necessarily be the credit card owner. The card and customer can be linked through the booking

Answer (score 0):

You need to control the order of insert operations because of the constraints that are applied on Booking and Payments.  You cannot insert into Booking until Holidays and Customers have been loaded.  You cannot insert into Payments until Booking and Credit Card have been loaded.  Customer, CreditCard and Holidays have no constraints and therefore no requirements in the order they must be loaded.